# Remove boxes around imshow when sharing X axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I try to stack several `imshow` elements, some extra white space appears around them in the vertical axis and the titles appear too close to the other figures.

I think that both issues are caused by the `sharex=True` but I do not know how to solve them.

`fig.tight_layout()` almost solves this problem, but it is incompatible with the colour bar on the side and makes some squares smaller than others.

The code that generates the image is

```
# Values is a [(ndarray, string)]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(values), sharex=True)
for ax, (value, plot_name) in zip(axes, values):
    im = ax.imshow(value, vmax=1.0, vmin=0.0)
    ax.set_title(plot_name)

# (Hack) Apply on the last one
plt.xticks(range(values.shape[1]), ticks, rotation=90)
plt.colorbar(im, ax=axes.ravel().tolist())

fig.savefig(output_name, bbox_inches="tight")
```

and an example image is:
[image]

Comment: Changing the first line to

`fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(foo), sharex=True, subplot_kw={"frame_on": False})`

makes the boxes disappear, though the ticks are then left floating in an awkward way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the aspect of the plots cannot be set to `"equal"` when `sharex=True` is used. There might be two solutions:

#### Not sharing axes

Sharing axes is not really necessary, since all subplots anyway have the same dimension. So the idea would be not to share any axes, but simply remove the ticklabels of the upper plots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

values = [np.random.rand(3,10) for i in range(3)]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(values))
for i, (ax, value) in enumerate(zip(axes, values)):
    im = ax.imshow(value, vmax=1.0, vmin=0.0)
    ax.set_title("title")
    ax.set_xticks(range(value.shape[1]))
    if i != len(axes)-1:
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
    else:
        plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)

plt.colorbar(im, ax=axes.ravel().tolist())


plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Using `ImageGrid`

Using `ImageGrid` from the `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1` module provides a grid specifically for plots of equal aspects. It can be used as follows. One main advantage here is that the colorbar would automatically be the same size as the subplots.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

values = [np.random.rand(3,10) for i in range(3)]

axes = ImageGrid(plt.figure(), 111,
                 nrows_ncols=(3,1),
                 axes_pad=0.3,
                 share_all=True,
                 cbar_location="right",
                 cbar_mode="single",
                 cbar_size="2%",
                 cbar_pad=0.15,
                 label_mode = "L"
                 )

for i, (ax, value) in enumerate(zip(axes, values)):
    im = ax.imshow(value, vmax=1.0, vmin=0.0)
    ax.set_title("title")
    ax.set_xticks(range(value.shape[1]))

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)

ax.cax.colorbar(im)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `gridspec_kw={"hspace": 0.8}` argument to the `plt.subplots` constructor made it work for me. That controls the vertical space between the subplots I believe

```
ticks = ["blah" for i in range(17)]
# Values is a [(ndarray, string)]
values = [(np.random.randn(3,17), "Title") for i in range(3)]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(values), sharex=True, gridspec_kw={"hspace": 0.8})
for ax, (value, plot_name) in zip(axes, values):
    im = ax.imshow(value, vmax=1.0, vmin=0.0)
    ax.set_title(plot_name)

# (Hack) Apply on the last one
plt.xticks(range(values[0][0].shape[1]), ticks, rotation=90)
plt.colorbar(im, ax=axes.ravel().tolist())

plt.show()
```

[image]